# Prototype.js 1.4.0 throws 'Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"' Error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to **override** `prototype.js` by adding in `setRequestHeaders` function `if()` with `continue;` to avoid specified **Header**:

```
for (var i = 0; i < requestHeaders.length; i += 2){
     if("Connection" === requestHeaders[i] || "Connection" === requestHeaders[i+1])
            continue;
     this.transport.setRequestHeader(requestHeaders[i], requestHeaders[i+1]);
  }
```

On IE9 this works properly without changes to `prototype.js`, but in other browsers (Chrome, Firefox etc.) the error in title occurs..

Thanks for any advice and help! :)

[EDIT]

Concerning duplication:
I found this topic, but it's not same. In duplicated topic there's a file which could be modified, but I cannot modify the code of `prototype.js`.

[EDIT2]

This code is in 1.4.0 (as written in the title), line about 661-685

```
setRequestHeaders: function() {
var requestHeaders =
  ['X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest',
   'X-Prototype-Version', Prototype.Version];

if (this.options.method == 'post') {
  requestHeaders.push('Content-type',
    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  /* Force "Connection: close" for Mozilla browsers to work around
   * a bug where XMLHttpReqeuest sends an incorrect Content-length
   * header. See Mozilla Bugzilla #246651.
   */
  if (this.transport.overrideMimeType)
    requestHeaders.push('Connection', 'close');
}

if (this.options.requestHeaders)
  requestHeaders.push.apply(requestHeaders, this.options.requestHeaders);

for (var i = 0; i < requestHeaders.length; i += 2){
    console.log(requestHeaders[i] + " AND " + requestHeaders[i+1]);
    //My edition - BEGIN;
    if("Connection" === requestHeaders[i] || "Connection" === requestHeaders[i+1])
            continue;
    //END;
  this.transport.setRequestHeader(requestHeaders[i], requestHeaders[i+1]);
  }
}
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: What's `.equals(...)`? That certainly isn't Javascript...

Comment: @epascarello No, it isn't. Show me that in the specs.

Comment: Ohh.. Whatever - I want to override actual `prototype.js` file with my modified version - how to do this? :)

Comment: @Tomalak `String.prototype.equals = function(X){ return this.toString()===X; };`  It can be valid JavaScript. ;)

Comment: Too bad this is not a dupe of what was posted, OP is asking how can the original code be altered. Reopening

Comment: Can' you just delete `connection` out of `requestHeaders`? To override it, you basically need to redefine the function.

Comment: I tried to modify this file, but seems like it is an external library - while opening the app the file is always same without my changes...

Comment: How did you override it? In the original? If you did, I bet it is cached. Clear your cache.

Comment: I am deploying this on Glassfish - this app works with Java, but some lines of code are written in JavaScript

Comment: @epascarello Not what I meant. Of course I know that you can extend the string prototype, but `.equals` does not exist by default (and it looks more like Java to me). So I asked the OP what that is, in order to determine what libraries are in use here.

Comment: @Rafcik Fair enough with regard to the close reason. Would have re-opened myself.

Comment: @Rafcik You might want to add more of your code. It's not clear to me where the snippet you show belongs to (it does look like it could be prototype.js code, but not from a recent version). Also show your calling code.

Comment: @Tomalak I've added code edition :) Thanks!

Comment: So you *are* modifying the library's code, after all? BTW, prototype 1.4 is *really* ancient. Is that a hard dependency or can you upgrade?

Comment: I have write access to this file, but looks like it's not updated after each deploying, as if it is downloaded from.. I dont know?
I cannot even find any reference to this in the app..
I am not sure if upgrading file to newer version will affect the code :/

Answer (score 1):

So it seems you want to change Prototype's behavior without touching the library code itself.

That's not a problem, you can swap out the `setRequestHeaders` function at run-time.

Include this after the `<script>` line that loads prototype, but before you do anything else.

```
// monkey-patch Prototype's Ajax request (the following is for Prototype 1.4!)
Ajax.Request.prototype.setRequestHeaders = function () {
  var requestHeaders =
    ['X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest',
     'X-Prototype-Version', Prototype.Version];

  if (this.options.method == 'post') {
    requestHeaders.push('Content-type',
      'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    /* Force "Connection: close" for Mozilla browsers to work around
     * a bug where XMLHttpReqeuest sends an incorrect Content-length
     * header. See Mozilla Bugzilla #246651.
     */
    if (this.transport.overrideMimeType)
      requestHeaders.push('Connection', 'close');
  }

  if (this.options.requestHeaders)
    requestHeaders.push.apply(requestHeaders, this.options.requestHeaders);

  for (var i = 0; i < requestHeaders.length; i += 2) {
    if (requestHeaders[i].toLowerCase() === "connection") continue;
    this.transport.setRequestHeader(requestHeaders[i], requestHeaders[i+1]);
  }
};
```

Comment: Will this completely @Override prototype's method?

Comment: Technically, it will *physically replace* the method ([see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch)). But in effect, yes.

Comment: toLowerCase is a javascript function, therefore it should have open/close brackets.
You could do the same check for connection as mentioned in the below code.

`if (requestHeaders[i].toLowerCase() != "connection") {
     this.transport.setRequestHeader(requestHeaders[i],requestHeaders[i+1]);`
     }

Comment: @Jeewantha Thanks for spotting that typo!

Answer (score 0):

Later versions of prototype.js (1.5+?) set the `Connection` header only to really old Firefox browsers, so this problem goes away with the upgrade.